# Call function in derived class from base class

Tags: c++, linux

I have a timer class in which when the timer elapses the TimeEventHdlr would be called. If there is a callback function provided then it will call that else will call the function within the class. What would be a better solution to call the derived class function when the timer elapses?

```
typedef void(*TimerCallback)();

struct Parm {
    TimerCallback clbk;
};

class TimerHdlr {
    TimerHdlr(Parm &parm);
    timer_t mTimerId;
    TimerCallback mTimerClbk;
    void StartTimer();
    void TimerFunc();
    static void TimeEventHdlr(sigval_t sigVal);
};

TimerHdlr::TimerHdlr(Parm &parm) : mTimerClbk(parm.clbk) {
    struct sigevent sigev;
    memset(&sigev, 0, sizeof(struct sigevent));
    sigev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = (void *)this;
    sigev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    sigev.sigev_notify_function = &TimerHdlr::TimeEventHdlr;
    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sigev, &mTimerId);
}

void TimerHdlr::StartTimer() {
    struct itimerspec timerSpec;
    timerSpec.it_interval.tv_sec = 0; /* oneshot timer */
    timerSpec.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    timerSpec.it_value.tv_sec = 10;
    timerSpec.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    timer_settime(mTimerId, 0, &timerSpec, NULL);
}

void TimerHdlr::TimerFunc() {}

/*static*/ void TimerHdlr::TimeEventHdlr(sigval_t val) {
    TimerHdlr *obj = static_cast<TimerHdlr*>(val.sival_ptr);
    if (obj->mTimerClbk == nullptr)
        obj->TimerFunc();
    else
        obj->mTimerClbk();
}
```

Derived class implementation:

```
class DerivedTimer: public TimerHdlr {
    static void TimeoutClbkHdlr(); 
};

Parm parm = {.clbk = DerivedTimer::TimeoutClbkHdlr};

DerivedTimer::DerivedTimer() : TimerHdlr(parm) {
}

/*static*/ void DerivedTimer::TimeoutClbkHdlr() {
// function to called when base timer elapses
}
```

Comment: Do you know about [virtual functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual)?

Answer (score 1):

Make `TimerFunc()` be [`virtual`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) in `TimerHdlr` and then override it in `DerivedTimer`. There is no need for a static `TimeoutClbkHdlr` method in `DerivedTimer`.

```cpp
typedef void(*TimerCallback)();

class TimerHdlr {
private:
    timer_t mTimerId;
    TimerCallback mTimerClbk;
    static void TimeEventHdlr(sigval_t sigVal);
protected:
    virtual void TimerFunc();
public:
    TimerHdlr(TimerCallback clbk = nullptr);
    void StartTimer();
};

TimerHdlr::TimerHdlr(TimerCallback clbk) : mTimerClbk(clbk) {
    struct sigevent sigev;
    memset(&sigev, 0, sizeof(struct sigevent));
    sigev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = (void *)this;
    sigev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    sigev.sigev_notify_function = &TimerHdlr::TimeEventHdlr;
    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sigev, &mTimerId);
}

void TimerHdlr::StartTimer() {
    struct itimerspec timerSpec;
    timerSpec.it_interval.tv_sec = 0; /* oneshot timer */
    timerSpec.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    timerSpec.it_value.tv_sec = 10;
    timerSpec.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    timer_settime(mTimerId, 0, &timerSpec, NULL);
}

void TimerHdlr::TimerFunc() {}

/*static*/ void TimerHdlr::TimeEventHdlr(sigval_t val) {
    TimerHdlr *obj = static_cast<TimerHdlr*>(val.sival_ptr);
    if (obj->mTimerClbk == nullptr)
        obj->TimerFunc();
    else
        obj->mTimerClbk();
}
```

```
class DerivedTimer: public TimerHdlr {
protected:
    void TimerFunc() override;
public:
    DerivedTimer();
};

DerivedTimer::DerivedTimer() : TimerHdlr() {
}

void DerivedTimer::TimerFunc() {
    // function to called when base timer elapses
}
```